# Customer Information Attribute in New Order Email Template

Tags: magento-1, email-templates, customer-attribute

I've scanned many posts but cannot get to bottom of this one.
I have created a custom Customer Information attribute and I need it to display on the New Order transactional email.

Any ideas? I have tried `{{var customer.getAccountno()}}` and a few others but it won't display.

My Code:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "accountno",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Account Number",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "accountno");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

to add the customer attribute in new order email, change the below file

Rewrite first `sendNewOrderEmail()` from `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to your local codepool.
Add `$email` in the template parameters.

```
$info = $this->getAccountno();
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'info'         => $info,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
```

Now you can access this variable like `{{var info}}` in the new sales order email template.

Answer (score 0):

for transectional email, you need set value via controller or observer and than you use `{{var customer.getAccountno()}}` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Magento 1.9.x

`{{var order.getCustomer().getData('your_customer_attribute_code')}}`